# separate map from location doesn't update location onCreate

Tags: android, android-location, android-maps-v2

This is the `getDeviceLocation` I am currently using.

```
 private void getDeviceLocation() {
    /*
     * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
     * cases when a location is not available.
     */
    try {
      if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
        Task<Location> locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        locationResult.addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
              SET_LOCATION_STATUS = 1;
              mMap.clear();
              // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
              mLastKnownLocation = location;//task.getResult();
             // showMap() method starts
              mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                  new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                      mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
              marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                  .position(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()))
                  .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon))
              );
              //showMap() method ends
              latlang.Lat = mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude();
              latlang.Lang = mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude();
            } else {
            ...}
```

I was trying to separate the location from the map part using another method as:

```
/*
  Attempt to seperate location and map
  */
  private void showMap(){
    if(MAP_LOCATION_SOURCE == 1){
      getDeviceLocation();
    }
    if (SET_LOCATION_STATUS ==1 ) {
      mMap.clear();
      Log.v("Location Available??????????", Double.toString(latlang.Lat));
      mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
          new LatLng(latlang.Lat, latlang.Lang), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
      marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(new LatLng(latlang.Lat, latlang.Lang))
          .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon))
      );
    }
  }
```

They are called/used as:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setHasOptionsMenu(true);

      // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
      if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
        mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        SET_LOCATION_STATUS = 1;
      }
    }
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, null, false);
    onSaveInstanceState(new Bundle());

    // Construct a FusedLocationProviderClient.
    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());
    getLocationPermission();
    getDeviceLocation();
//    showMap();

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;

    getLocationPermission();
    updateLocationUI();
    getDeviceLocation();
//    showMap();
```

This is working without any error, but doesn't take the location/camera position from Bundle as in the case when map is inside the `getDeviceLocation`. When I use start using the app, the location and map get updated.

How I can separate the location and map properly then?

Comment: First of all can you tell me why are you moving your camera at both places? at onSuccess() method and also in showMap() method?

Comment: oh...no...as you see, onSuccess's moveCamera is actually inside showMap. lines between showmap method starts[ends] will be commented if the method works propelry.

Comment: okay okay...i want to know what you exactly want to achieve? As far i understand you want to move camera on users location when user opens map and you want to do all this stuff in seperate method. right? correct me if i am going wrong.

Comment: Yes, thats the thing. Basically, I want to separate location and map part, so that the map can be updated from various source, like saved location, place picker etc, not only from device location.